# How do I skip a line in perl if an error occurs?

Tags: perl, parsing, logging, backup

I'm relativity new to perl and I'm trying to split and parse out data from a log file. The log file contains information of when a backup was and wither it was successful or not.

However at one point in the log file an entry repeats itself and is causing issues parsing the data. How can I skip the entry if it doesn't parse?

Normal entry on top and the problematic entry below.

```
> $VAR1 = 'Thu Jul 31 00:35:00 2014'; 
> $VAR2 = 'Daily Backup for (Wed) Jul. 30, 2014 
> STATUS: Successful Thu Jul 31 00:37:22 2014';
> VAR3 = 'Backup Completed: Thu Jul 31 00:40:07 2014


> $VAR1 = 'Fri May 16 00:35:00 2014';
> $VAR2 = 'Daily Backup for (Thu) May. 15, 2014
> STATUS: Successful Fri May 16 00:37:43 2014';
> $VAR3 = 'Daily Backup for (Thu) May. 15, 2014
> STATUS: Successful Fri May 16 00:39:54 2014';
> $VAR4 = 'Backup Completed: Fri May 16 00:42:37 2014



my $stdout = ("cat backup.log");
my @lines = split(/Backup Started: /, $stdout);
shift @lines;

  foreach(@lines)
{

my @backupstarted = split(/\n\n/,$_);
my $start = $backupstarted[0];

my @types = split(/ Backup /, $backuptype);
my $type = $types[0];

my @statuses = split(/ /, $backupstatus);
$statuses[1] =~ s/\://g;
my $status = $statuses[1];

my @enddate = split(/ /, $backup);
my $end = $enddate[0];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "issues"? What do you mean by "doesn't parse"?

Comment: @choroba I receive `Use of uninitialized value $backup in split at ./backup_stats.pl line 90.` as this particular log entry(shown above) differs from the rest. I've split and parsed out the data on the basis of an normal log entry. So if an entry differs from the norm and cannot be split and parsed I'd like to skip the entry and move on to the next.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

Let's open the file in the normal way, first:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'backup.log' or die "Couldn't open `backup.log': $!";

my %backup;
my $current_backup;
while (<$fh>) {
    # when we see a new date...
    # set up a new hash ref for its details
    if (/^\w{3} \w{3} \d+ [0-9:]+ 20\d\d/) {
        chomp;
        $backup{$_} = {};
        $current_backup = $_;
    }

    # look for other known types of lines
    if ($current_backup) {
        if (/^(\w+) Backup /) {
            if ($backup{$current_backup}{type}) {
                delete $backup{$current_backup};
                $current_backup = '';
            } else {
                $backup{$current_backup}{type} = $1;
            }
        } elsif (/^STATUS: (\w+)/) {
            $backup{$current_backup}{status} = $1;
        } elsif (/^Backup Completed: (.*)/) {
            $backup{$current_backup}{completed} = $1;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
```

But even then, I don't think you *actually* want to skip the entry if it isn't normal.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll give your solution a try. I'm actually using my `$stdout = $ssh->capture("cat path to log file");` to open the file. As I'm running the script remotely via SSH.

I'd like to skip the entry if it isn't normal, the most important part is if the STATUS: was a success or a failure.